# Вертикальный Slick slider на весь экран. Как сделать чтобы после слайда показывался футер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, slick.js, слайдер

Прошу помочь с реализацией вертикального slick слайдера на весь экран, после которого есть футер высотой 300 px. 
Цели - каждый слайд на весь экран, листание слайдов с помощью mouse scroll, чтобы футер был виден при скроле и нормальной ширины(300px);
В тот момент когда футер виден - кнопка должна пропасть.
Спасибо каждому кто не пройдет мимо!
Посоветуйте какой использовать слайдер, если считаете что слик не очень.

Мой код - `codepen.io/Rainspistols/pen/dyPYmEV`

Comment: Ничего не понятно к сожалению, в ваших хитросплетениях.

Comment: @РустамГимранов https://codepen.io/Rainspistols/pen/dyPYmEV, попытался переписать вопрос яснее. Спасибо